# press event passes through overlaying <View/> on andriod

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

On IOS my app works correctly but on android underlaying views receive button presses. How to stop this? I've seen posts about this but they aren't solved.

```
        <View style={{
        width:'100%', height:'100%',
        position:'absolute', justifyContent:'center',
        alignItems:'center',zIndex: 9999,
        elevation:1, backgroundColor:'rgba(100,0,0,.5)'}}
        >
        
        </View>
```

this simply draws a transparent fill across the screen, and technically it should prevent me from interacting with the view below, at least on IOS it does. but not on android.  I tried adding pointerEvent attribute but no luck. its brazy..

Answer (score 0):

I solved this late last night...  the issue for some reason is. you have to make sure that the thing you are trying to render is the last item so... lets say you have this:

```
<button></button>
<View></View>
<Content></Content>

has to be like this:

<View></View>
<Content></Content>
<button></button>
```

I have no clue ! this seems so random